# My JS clock without date method don't work

Tags: javascript

the code is below. I tried to do a clock with this method without using "date".
Basically I think the logic is right but probably something in the syntax is wrong.
The output is just 1. not any movement. I want the output be - 0:0:0
Thank for help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>on submit</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="time"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

```
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

function myTimer() {
    var sec = 0;
    var min = 0;
    var hr = 0;
    sec++;
    if(sec==60) {
        min++;
        sec=0;
    }

    if(min==60)
    {
        min = 0;
        hr++;
    }
    return(hr+":"+min+":"+sec);
}

document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = myVar;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you assign the result of a call to setInterval to a variable - **myVar** in your case - you receive an integer number which is an unique id for that particular interval - not the actual time you expect to be returned by the **myTimer** function.

So instead of returning the result from the **myTimer** function, set the innerHTML of the time element in there.

```
var interval = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

function myTimer() {
    var sec = 0;
    var min = 0;
    var hr = 0;
    sec++;
    if(sec==60) {
        min++;
        sec=0;
    }

    if(min==60)
    {
        min = 0;
        hr++;
    }
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML=hr+":"+min+":"+sec;
}
```

As a side note: your time will always be 0 since you're resetting the variable **sec** to **0** inside myTimer with every call. So put the definitions for sec, min and hr outside of the function.

Here's an example - just click on 'Run code snippet':

```js
var interval = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
var sec = 0;
var min = 0;
var hr = 0;

function myTimer() {
  sec++;
  if (sec == 60) {
    min++;
    sec = 0;
  }

  if (min == 60) {
    min = 0;
    hr++;
  }
  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = hr + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
}
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
```

Comment: hey, I understand what you have said. You right that was my mistake with the return. But still, it doesn't work. the output is 0:0:1 and it's not moving at all.

Comment: I edited my answer above since there was another little mistake I've spotted.

Comment: MMMM i get it, thank for it !!! it's work and it is very coo. gree arraow !!!

Comment: No problem lir sim - glad I could help! =)